# The input stream is not a valid binary format. Serialization issue

Tags: c#, serialization, stream, binary, byte

Hello I'm having some problems with this piece of code:

This:

```
public void SendRegistrationPacket()
    {
        Packet p = new Packet(PacketType.Registration, "server");
        p.Gdata.Add(id);
        clientSocket.Send(p.ToBytes());
    }
```

sends `p.ToBytes()` to this:

```
public Packet(byte[] packetbytes)
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(packetbytes);
        Packet p = (Packet)bf.Deserialize(ms);
        ms.Close();
        this.Gdata = p.Gdata;
        this.packetInt = p.packetInt;
        this.packetBool = p.packetBool;
        this.senderID = p.senderID;
        this.packetType = p.packetType;
    }
```

I'm getting following error at `Packet p = (Packet)bf.Deserialize(ms);` :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 35-2D-33-39-61-30-63-65-33-65-37-38-33-65-05-FB-FF ...

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong...

Could anybody help me out?

Many thanks for your time!

---- EDIT ----

Server.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ServerData;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Server;

namespace Server
{
    class Server
    {

        static Socket listenerSocket;
        static List<ClientData> clients;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Starting Server On: " + Packet.GetIP4Address());
            listenerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            clients = new List<ClientData>();

            IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(Packet.GetIP4Address()), 4242);

            listenerSocket.Bind(ip);

            Thread listenThread = new Thread(ListenThread);
            listenThread.Start();

        } //Start server


        //Listner - listens for clients trying to connect
        static void ListenThread()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                listenerSocket.Listen(0);

                clients.Add(new ClientData(listenerSocket.Accept()));

            }
        }

        //ClientData thread - receives data from each client individually
        public static void Data_IN(object cSocket)
        {
            Socket clientSocket = (Socket)cSocket;
            byte[] buffer;
            int readBytes;
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {

                    buffer = new byte[clientSocket.SendBufferSize];
                    readBytes = clientSocket.Receive(buffer);

                    if (readBytes > 0)
                    {
                        //handle data
                        Packet packet = new Packet(buffer);
                        DataManger(packet);
                    }
                }
                catch (SocketException ex)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("A Client Had Disconnected!");
                }
            }
        }

        //Data Manager
        public static void DataManger(Packet p)
        {
            switch (p.packetType)
            {
                case PacketType.Chat:
                    foreach (ClientData c in clients)
                    {
                        c.clientSocket.Send(p.ToBytes());
                    }
                    break;
                case PacketType.Connect:
                    //Console.WriteLine("User: \"" + p.Gdata[0] + "\" Has connected from IP: " + p.Gdata[1]);

                    string response = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\json.txt");//"{\"one\": \"0\",\"two\": \"45\",\"three\": \"5\",\"four\": \"86\",\"five\": \"75\",\"six\": \"32\",\"Count\": \"6883197667\"}";

                    response = response.Substring(1, response.Length - 2);

                    Rootobject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(response);

                    foreach (ClientData c in clients)
                    {
                        if (c.id == p.Gdata[1])
                        {
                            Packet packet = new Packet(PacketType.Message, "Server");
                            packet.Gdata.Add(root.one);
                            packet.Gdata.Add(root.two);
                            packet.Gdata.Add(root.three);
                            packet.Gdata.Add(root.four);
                            packet.Gdata.Add(root.five);
                            packet.Gdata.Add(root.six);
                            packet.Gdata.Add(root.Count);
                            packet.Gdata.Add(root.Found);
                            c.clientSocket.Send(packet.ToBytes());
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                case PacketType.Message:

                    List<Rootobject> data = new List<Rootobject>();

                    data.Add(
                        new Rootobject
                        {
                            one = p.Gdata[0],
                            two = p.Gdata[1],
                            three = p.Gdata[2],
                            four = p.Gdata[3],
                            five = p.Gdata[4],
                            six = p.Gdata[5],
                            Count = p.Gdata[6],
                            Found = p.Gdata[7]
                        }
                        );

                    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.ToArray());

                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\json.txt", json);

                    string responseB = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\json.txt");

                    responseB = responseB.Substring(1, responseB.Length -2);

                    Rootobject rootB = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(responseB);

                    foreach (ClientData c in clients)
                    {
                        if (c.id == p.Gdata[8])
                        {
                            Packet packet = new Packet(PacketType.Message, "Server");
                            packet.Gdata.Add(rootB.one);
                            packet.Gdata.Add(rootB.two);
                            packet.Gdata.Add(rootB.three);
                            packet.Gdata.Add(rootB.four);
                            packet.Gdata.Add(rootB.five);
                            packet.Gdata.Add(rootB.six);
                            packet.Gdata.Add(rootB.Count);
                            packet.Gdata.Add(rootB.Found);
                            c.clientSocket.Send(packet.ToBytes());
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                case PacketType.Disconnect:
                    Console.WriteLine("User: \"" + p.Gdata[0] + "\" Has disconnected from IP: " + p.Gdata[1]);
                    break;
            }
        }



    }
}
```

ClientData.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using ServerData;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace Server
{
    class ClientData
    {

        public Socket clientSocket;
        public Thread clientThread;
        public string id;

        public ClientData()
        {
            id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            clientThread = new Thread(Server.Data_IN);
            clientThread.Start(clientSocket);
            SendRegistrationPacket();
        }
        public ClientData(Socket clientSocket)
        {
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
            id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            clientThread = new Thread(Server.Data_IN);
            clientThread.Start(clientSocket);
            SendRegistrationPacket();
        }

        public void SendRegistrationPacket()
        {
            //Packet p = new Packet(PacketType.Registration, "server");
            //p.Gdata.Add(id);
            ////clientSocket.Send(p.ToBytes());
            //BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            //MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            Packet p = new Packet(PacketType.Registration, "server");
            p.Gdata.Add(id);

            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bf.Serialize(ms, p);
            clientSocket.Send(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Packet.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ServerData;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Net;

namespace ServerData
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Packet
    {
        public List<string> Gdata;
        public int packetInt;
        public bool packetBool;
        public string senderID;
        public PacketType packetType;

        public Packet(PacketType type, string senderID)
        {
            Gdata = new List<string>();
            this.senderID = senderID;
            this.packetType = type;
        }

        public Packet(byte[] packetbytes)
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(packetbytes);
            Packet p = (Packet)bf.Deserialize(ms);
            ms.Close();
            this.Gdata = p.Gdata;
            this.packetInt = p.packetInt;
            this.packetBool = p.packetBool;
            this.senderID = p.senderID;
            this.packetType = p.packetType;
        }

        public byte[] ToBytes()
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            bf.Serialize(ms, this);

            byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
            ms.Close();

            return bytes;
        }

        public static string GetIP4Address()
        {
            IPAddress[] ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());

            foreach (IPAddress ip in ips)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    return ip.ToString();
                }
            }

            return "127.0.0.1";
        }

    }

    public enum PacketType
    {
        Registration,
        Chat,
        Connect,
        Disconnect,
        Message
    }
}
```

Client.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ServerData;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Client
{
    class Client
    {
        public static Socket master;
        public static string id;

        #region MD5 Crack vars
        public static bool found = false;
        public static string charsS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQESTUVWXYZ0123456789~!@#$%^&*_-+=`|\\(){}[]:;\"'<>,.?/ëÿüïöäêÛîôâéýúíóáé";
        public static int length = 6;
        public static int threadCountInt = 1;
        public static int[] count;
        public static long counter = 0;
        public static long counterS = 0;
        public static string test = "";
        public static char[] chars;
        public static DateTime start;
        public static int threadCount = 0;
        public static List<string> threads = new List<string>();
        public static string result;
        public static string[] currentA;
        public static Object thisLock = new Object();
       // public static IniFile ini;
        public static long runtime;
        public static string current;
        #endregion

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Number of threads to run: ");
            threadCountInt = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            chars = charsS.ToArray();
            start = DateTime.Now;
            currentA = new string[threadCountInt];

            count = new int[length];

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write("Enter Host IP Address: ");
                string ip = Console.ReadLine();

                master = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), 4242);

                try
                {
                    master.Connect(ipe);
                    Packet p = new Packet(PacketType.Connect, id);
                    p.Gdata.Add(Packet.GetIP4Address());
                    p.Gdata.Add(id);
                    master.Send(p.ToBytes());
                    break;
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Could Not Connect To Host!");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
            Thread t = new Thread(Data_IN);
            t.Start();

            //Packet packet = new Packet(PacketType.Connect, id);
            //packet.Gdata.Add(Packet.GetIP4Address());
            //packet.Gdata.Add(id);
            //master.Send(packet.ToBytes());

            //while (true)
            //{
            //    Console.Write("::>");
            //    string input = Console.ReadLine();
            //    if (input.ToLower() == "exit" || input.ToLower() == "close")
            //    {
            //        Packet p = new Packet(PacketType.Disconnect, id);
            //        p.Gdata.Add(name);
            //        p.Gdata.Add(Packet.GetIP4Address());
            //        master.Send(p.ToBytes());
            //        Environment.Exit(0);
            //    }
            //    else
            //    {
            //        Packet p = new Packet(PacketType.Chat, id);
            //        p.Gdata.Add(name);
            //        p.Gdata.Add(input);
            //        master.Send(p.ToBytes());
            //    }
            //}

            Thread t2 = new Thread(statusUpdate);
            t2.Start();

            for (int tt = 0; tt < threadCountInt; tt++)
            {
                new Thread(() => work(tt - 1)).Start();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
            Environment.Exit(0);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Data_IN()
        {
            byte[] buffer;
            int readBytes;

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    buffer = new byte[master.SendBufferSize];
                    readBytes = master.Receive(buffer);

                    if (readBytes > 0)
                    {
                        DataManager(new Packet(buffer));
                    }
                }
                catch (SocketException ex)
                {
                    ConsoleColor c = Console.ForegroundColor;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Lost Connection To The Server!");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = c;
                    Console.Write("::>");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
            }
        }

        static void DataManager(Packet p)
        {
            switch (p.packetType)
            {
                case PacketType.Registration:
                    id = p.Gdata[0];
                    break;
                case PacketType.Chat:
                    ConsoleColor c = Console.ForegroundColor;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                    Console.WriteLine(p.Gdata[0] + ": " + p.Gdata[1]);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = c;
                    Console.Write("::>");
                    break;
                case PacketType.Message:
                    count[0] = int.Parse(p.Gdata[0]);
                    count[1] = int.Parse(p.Gdata[1]);
                    count[2] = int.Parse(p.Gdata[2]);
                    count[3] = int.Parse(p.Gdata[3]);
                    count[4] = int.Parse(p.Gdata[4]);
                    count[5] = int.Parse(p.Gdata[5]);
                    counter = long.Parse(p.Gdata[6]);
                    break;
            }
        }

        public static void statusUpdate()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            long tmp = 0;
            while (!found)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(" " + threadCount.ToString() + " Threads Running");
                Console.Write(" ");
                foreach (string s in threads)
                {
                    if (s != threads[threads.Count - 1])
                    {
                        Console.Write(s + ", ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(s);
                    }

                }
                Console.WriteLine();

                Console.WriteLine(" " + (counterS + counter).ToString() + "/" + (long)Math.Pow(charsS.Length, 6) + " (" + ((float)((float)(counterS + counter) / (float)Math.Pow(charsS.Length, 6)) * 100).ToString() + "%)");
                Console.WriteLine(" " + ((long)Math.Pow(charsS.Length, 6) - counter).ToString() + " Left");

                if (counter > 0 && TimeSpanInSecs(start) > 0)
                {
                    tmp = (counter / TimeSpanInSecs(start));
                }
                else
                {
                    tmp = 0;
                }

                Console.WriteLine(" " + tmp.ToString() + " H/S");
                if (tmp > 0)
                {
                    long ETA = ((long)Math.Pow(charsS.Length, 6) - (counterS + counter)) / tmp;
                    Console.WriteLine(" " + string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", ETA / 3600, (ETA / 60) % 60, ETA % 60) + " ETA");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" NaN ETA");
                }

                long totalRun = runtime + TimeSpanInSecs(start);
                Console.WriteLine(" Current Session: " + string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", TimeSpanInSecs(start) / 3600, (TimeSpanInSecs(start) / 60) % 60, TimeSpanInSecs(start) % 60));
                Console.WriteLine(" Total Run Time:  " + string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", totalRun / 3600, (totalRun / 60) % 60, totalRun % 60));

                Console.WriteLine(" Current: " + current);

                if (found)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" Result: " + result);
                }

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        public static string MD5hasher(string value)
        {
            HashAlgorithm ha = MD5.Create();
            Byte[] cryptedData = ha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value));

            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < cryptedData.Length; i++)
            {
                sBuilder.Append(cryptedData[i].ToString("x2"));
            }
            ha.Clear();
            return sBuilder.ToString();
        }

        public static long TimeSpanInSecs(DateTime start)
        {
            TimeSpan tmp = DateTime.Now - start;
            long seconds = tmp.Seconds;
            seconds += tmp.Minutes * 60;
            seconds += (tmp.Hours * 60) * 60;
            seconds += ((tmp.Days * 24) * 60) * 60;

            return seconds;

        }

        public static void work(int Tid)
        {
            int localCount = 0;
            threadCount++;
            threads.Add(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
            while (!found)
            {
                test = string.Empty;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int x = 0; x < length; x++)
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            sb.Append(chars[count[x]]);
                            break;
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }

                }

                test = sb.ToString();
                current = test;

                count[count.Length - 1] = count[count.Length - 1] + 1;

                for (int y = count.Length; y >= 0; y--)
                {
                    if (y != 0)
                    {
                        if (count[y - 1] >= chars.Length - 1)
                        {
                            if (y > 1)
                            {
                                count[y - 2]++;
                            }
                            count[y - 1] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (count[y] == chars.Length - 1)
                        {
                            count[y] = 0;
                        }
                    }

                }

                if (MD5hasher(test) == "de99823d330004610cba3592ce7382b8")
                {
                    result = test;
                    found = true;
                }


                localCount++;

                //lock (thisLock)
                //{
                //    counter += localCount;
                //    localCount = 0;
                //};

                Packet p = new Packet(PacketType.Message, id);
                foreach (int i in count)
                {
                    p.Gdata.Add(i.ToString());
                }
                p.Gdata.Add(localCount.ToString());
                localCount = 0;
                p.Gdata.Add(found.ToString());
                p.Gdata.Add(id);

                master.Send(p.ToBytes());

                if (found)
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

JSON.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Server
{
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public string one { get; set; }
        public string two { get; set; }
        public string three { get; set; }
        public string four { get; set; }
        public string five { get; set; }
        public string six { get; set; }
        public string Count { get; set; }
        public string Found { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for p.ToBytes()? If its not serialized in the same way as its deserialized you will get this error.

Comment: Yup, you should use a `BinaryFormatter` to generate the Byte Array to send.

Comment: Is the `Packet.cs` in a DLL that is shared between the client and server, or have you copied the code into each one?

Comment: @Sidewinder94 No you should not, `BinaryFormatter` is not intended to be used with machine to machine communication or for persistent storage. The only thing it is intended to be used for is IPC between processes on the same machine. It is extremely change intolerant and if you do not have the exact same binaries on both sides of the wire you often can not desearalize your data. Use a 3rd party formatter like [ProtoBuff-net](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) instead.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is from

```
readBytes = clientSocket.Receive(buffer);

if (readBytes > 0)
{
    //handle data
    Packet packet = new Packet(buffer);
    DataManger(packet);
}
```

One send from the client does not equal one receive on the server. You need "[Message Frameing](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html)", your `Packet` only contains the first part of the data that was sent.

The easiest solution is first send the length of the byte array then have the receiving side receive only that length, allocate a buffer of that size then loop until it has fully filled the buffer.

Here is a quick example of the receiving side

```
private static byte[] ReadFully(Socket clientSocket, int length)
{
    int offset = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
    while(offset < length)
    {
        int read = clientSocket.Receive(buffer, offset, length - offset, SocketFlags.None);
        if(read = 0)
           return null; //Socket closed
        offset += read;
    }
    return buffer;
}


//read the length
byte[] lengthBuffer = ReadFully(clientSocket, 4);
if(lengthBuffer == null)
{
    //Do something about the closed connection
}
int length = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBuffer, 0);

//read the number of bytes specified by the length.
byte[] packetBuffer = ReadFully(clientSocket, length);

if (packetBuffer != null)
{
    //handle data
    Packet packet = new Packet(packetBuffer);
    DataManger(packet);
}
```

I leave it to you to do the sending side.

Comment: This looks good, and is possibly a better way of doing it then what I had, but it doesn't help me to solve my problem :/

I still get the exact same error the exact same place

Comment: BinaryFormatter works terribly for communication between machines because the two sides must be using the exact same files to serialize and deserialize. Try switching to [Protobuf-net](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)

Comment: Thanks, helped me identify an issue where I wasn't fully reading the data from the socket before attempting to process.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous commenters.  It's not clear what your ToBytes() method is doing.  What you should be doing is something like this:

```
public void SendRegistrationPacket()
    {
        Packet p = new Packet(PacketType.Registration, "server");
        p.Gdata.Add(id);

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bf.Serialize(ms, p);
        clientSocket.Send(ms.ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, that's odd, as it is working for me.  Can you paste in more of the code you're using on both ends (the serialization and the deserialization, and anything in between to transfer the data from one end to the other)?

Comment: I updated the original post with all my code (hopefully that will help you help me)

The examples I gave are from ClientData.cs line 37-51 and Packet.cs line 29-39